# Cannot get wordpress session username outside of installation folder

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies, content-management-system

My folder structure:

```
www.domain.com/myscript.php
www.domain.com/blog/wp-load.php
www.domain.com/blog/bridge.php
```

Bridge.php:

```
include('wp-config.php');
include('wp-includes/pluggable.php');
echo $current_user->user_login;
```

Opening this file manually in my browser correctly output the current logged in username. The problem is that i also need the username in myscript.php which is in the parent folder, outside wordpress install

myscript.php is just:

```
include("blog/bridge.php");
```

I have tried everything i could think of:
- installed the plugin "root cookie" to enable cookies outside installation dir
- if i check firefox cookies, it is correctly set to "/" and not to "/blog"
- also the following is set is wp-config.php:
    define('SITECOOKIEPATH','/');
    define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH','/');
- tried including different wordpress core files
- setting paths including the filesystem root doesn't change anything
- including the wordpress files in myscript.php instead of bridge.php doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

You need to include wp-load.php in your myscripts.php file as the first thing.  Including this one file will "load" all of WordPress for the page to use.  Basically, all WordPress functions and variables become available to that page.

```
include('blog/wp-load.php');
```

**EDIT**

This actually does work... Make your MyScript.php look like this for testing:

```
include( 'blog/wp-load.php');  
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
print_r($current_user);
```

You will get the correct information, or an empty WP_User object.  If it's empty then it's because the cookies are only valid inside your blog folder.  Modify your wp-config.php file to change the cookie domain:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Set_Cookie_Domain

Comment: Already tried that, just tryed again and it doesn't change anything. The page is blank and username isn't displayed

Comment: @JoLibertaire, I updated my answer last week... did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You actually just need to do this: This will make sure that you can use have access to theme and child them hooks. This will also setup the rest of the environment, including `wp-config.php` and `wp-includes/pluggable.php`

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require ('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

Comment: if i put the code in /myscript.php instead of /blog/bridge.php then it does output the username, but it also print the wordpress blog header and display default wordpress 404 page... I just want to get the username to use it in another script, not parse the whole wordpress headers